# rust: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime

Tags: rust

I'm working on a toy ray tracer project in Rust and am hung up on a lifetime-related error. I've stripped down my code to the following self-contained failing case:

```
struct Material {}

pub struct Sphere<'a> {
    material: &'a Material,
}

pub trait AnySceneObject {}

impl<'a> AnySceneObject for Sphere<'a> {}

pub struct Scene {
    objects: Vec<Box<AnySceneObject>>,
}

fn main() {
    let material = Material {};
    let boxed_sphere: Box<AnySceneObject> = Box::new(Sphere { material: &material });
    Scene { objects: vec![boxed_sphere] };
}
```

which complains

```
error[E0597]: `material` does not live long enough
  --> main.rs:17:74
   |
17 |     let boxed_sphere: Box<AnySceneObject> = Box::new(Sphere { material: &material });
   |                                                                          ^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
18 |     Scene { objects: vec![boxed_sphere] };
19 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
  = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...

error: aborting due to previous error(s)
```

I want to use traits to define objects in the scene, but I want the `Scene` object to own them. My current understanding is that this means I need `Box` or something equivalent because trait objects are of unknown size.

I also want objects to share references to `Material`s, since there won't be that many of them and though they're relatively simple and `Copy`able, I don't want literally tens or hundreds of thousands of identical copies of the same thing (hence using `&'a Material`).

I'm confused why it's problematic to pass `&material` here though: since values are dropped latest-first, wouldn't `Scene` be dropped first, allowing `boxed_sphere` to be dropped (since it now owns a `Vec` that owns that `Box`), which it then is, allowing `material` to be dropped, no problem? It seems like it should live at least as long as the other two values in the function, since I'm holding onto the value with the name `material` for the scope of the whole function.

Also somewhat confusingly, commenting out the instantiation of `Scene` fixes the issue for reasons I don't understand.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, if you have hundreds of thousands of scene objects, putting them in a box (which is basically a heap object) is definitely not a good idea.

The error is called because the `Box`'s content must not have any reference that might expire. You can move a `Box` around and it may never be deleted until the end of the process, so any references it holds must have `'static` lifetime.

You can fix it by using `Box<T + 'a>` to indicate that it will have a limited lifetime:

```
pub struct Scene<'a> {
    objects: Vec<Box<AnySceneObject + 'a>>,
}
```

You can also use `Vec<&Trait>` to store a collection of references to different objects implementing a trait. The following code compiles:

```
pub struct Scene<'a> {
    objects: Vec<&'a AnySceneObject>,
}

fn main() {
    let material = Material {};
    let sphere = Sphere { material: &material };
    Scene {
        objects: vec![&sphere] 
    };
}
```

If you know all possible implementations of your trait, you can replace it with a enum. This would make the code more performant, as you would have a vector owning enums instead of references.

Comment: Questions! (1) Aren't these objects going to be on the heap anyway? Does `Box` add a second level of indirection, in that case? (2) In your second code snippet, it works because `main` owns a single `sphere` handle, but if I dynamically generate a `Vec<&AnySceneObject>` (say, from a file), something needs to own the objects (right?), hence my use of `Box` (I realize this was elided in my simplified example). (3) Where does inferred `'static` come from? The fact that this is in `main`? (4) Enums sound better for this. Where can I read up on how they compare to references in this context?